# Where to find shapefile basemap for the Indian Ocean?

Tags: data, indian-ocean

I need to plot point data over a basemap of the Indian Ocean.

Can anyone tell me where I can find such a basemap in shapefile format?

Comment: Welcome to the GIS StackExchange! Please do tell us what you've done so far next time. That way, you'll save us the trouble of suggesting things you've tried already.

Answer (score 10):

Try [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/), they have ocean data as ESRI Shapefiles, you will however need to split out just the Indian Ocean from the dataset.

Answer (score 4):

VLIZ provides [world maritime boundaries](http://www.vliz.be/vmdcdata/marbound/) under a reasonable license. See [their site](http://www.vliz.be/vmdcdata/marbound/download.php) for specific downloads.